# Counting a number of keywords in Excel within a range of specific keywords

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, keyword

I know how to count a series of keywords in Excel. I use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($CE$2:$CE$43,(G2:AP2))))
```

However, what would be the Excel formula if I want to count the number of keywords that exist only within +/-3 words around "risk" in the selected rows?

Consider this sentence: "**Political uncertainty generates economic risk which stagnates economic activities.**" If my keywords are `political`, `uncertainty`, `stagnates`, and `economic`, the total count of keywords within +/- 3 words around "risk" will be 4, i.e., `uncertainty`, `stagnates`, and `economic`. "economic" appears twice in the sentence. `political` will be excluded since it is out of range.

Comment: It's going to be a lot easier to do this programmatically than with a formula.

Comment: ^^^ and with a tool that supports GREP searches

Comment: Try this... https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string ... here you can nth word from the given sentence... Idea is using search/find, first split sentence into 2 parts (before & after risk)... then get -3 & +3 words respectively...

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE("a a a "&A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::s[4]='risk']/following::*[position()<8]")&"*",C1:C4,0)))
```

This would in order:

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE("a a a "&A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` - Create a valid xml-string to process with xpath;
- `"//s[following::s[4]='risk']/following::*[position()<8]"` - A valid xpath 1.0 expression to retrieve only upto seven nodes with `risk` in the middle. In more detail: `//s[following::s[4]='risk']` will get the node where the following sibling on 4 indices to it's right will equal `risk` (case-sensitive), we then take all following siblings from that position with `/following::*` where we limit the returned nodes to a max of seven with `[position()<8]`. Now it would also make sense why we concatenate `a a a`  with the string from `A1` since `risk` could appear at the start of the string or less then three words in;
- `MATCH()` - Will then check if any of the returned nodes start with any of the words in `C1:C4` using a wildcard. This is to prevent possible punctuation to avoid matching;
- `SUM()` and `ISNUMBER()` prepended with double unary will lastly make a summation of hits.

***Note:*** The answer is not 3 **but** 4! Since 'economic' is to be counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following formula if you have Microsoft-365 with most recent release.

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")),y,MATCH("risk",x,0),z,INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(y+2,1,y-3)),COUNT(XMATCH(D1:D4,z,0)))
```

[image]